# what 's difference between android system user and linux root user

Tags: android

When I connect my phone to a computer and use `adb shell` command to communicate with my phone and input `ps` command to output processes info that currently run on my phone, I find two special users: one is root, the other is system.

As far as I know, Android is based on linux, so the root user is the biggest authority user. However I'm confused about the system user. Maybe I can consider it as a normal user in Linux system, but it is special in Android: it has a lot of permissions related to Android.

Can someone tell me the real difference between root user and system user, and why Android need to add a system user?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

As far as Linux is concerned, the `system` user is just a regular user (UID 1000). Android services however give it special permissions and you can get access to pretty much anything. Most services have code like this somewhere:

```
private static final void enforceSystemOrRoot(String message) {
    final int uid = Binder.getCallingUid();
    if (uid != Process.SYSTEM_UID && uid != 0) {
        throw new SecurityException(message);
    }
}
```

What that does is deny access to anyone who is not root or `system`. The `shell` user (UID 2000) (what you get when doing `adb shell`) is another user with a lot of power (member of many groups). Cf.

`system`:

```
 $ su 1000
 $ id
 uid=1000(system) gid=1000(system)
 groups=1003(graphics),1004(input),1007(log),1009(mount),
 1011(adb),1015(sdcard_rw),1028(sdcard_r),3001(net_bt_admin),
 3002(net_bt),3003(inet),3006(net_bw_stats)
```

`shell`:

```
$ adb shell
shell@android:/ $ id
uid=2000(shell) gid=2000(shell)   
groups=1003(graphics),1004(input),1007(log),1009(mount),
1011(adb),1015(sdcard_rw),1028(sdcard_r),3001(net_bt_admin),
3002(net_bt),3003(inet),3006(net_bw_stats)
```

Android uses a separate user for every app, and system services also have their dedicated users (`media`, `radio`, `wifi`, etc.). Very few things run as root (mostly native daemons).

Comment: So, if I got SYSYEM privs, could I use that to root the device or will I need true uid 0?

Comment: If you manage to get to `system`, you still need to find a way to elevate privileges to root. You need to a vulnerability in a privileged service in order to do that, however.

Comment: @NikolayElenkov How do I use system user in adb shell? When I do su 1000 on Samsung 4, it says su command not found...

Answer (score 0):

system user can not access other user's files.

If you do:
ls -l /data/data/com.google.android.gm/shared_prefs/

You will got 'permission denied'

If you are root user, you can do anything.
You can access all the file system, wipe all the data.

You can also reboot the phone, etc.