# Why is the output of an adb command different when run from adb shell and run from Android Application?

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

I am relatively new to android and I just came across adb shell commands which provide a lot of useful things. My issue is that when I execute the command **"top -bn1"** using adb shell from terminal it gives me a bunch of processes with users - root, system and other users. But when I run the same command from an application using **Runtime.getRuntime().exec("top -bn1")** the ouput is totally different and only processes for a particular user are displayed.

Here is the adb output -
[image]

And here is the code in the app and its output -

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("top -bn1");
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
    String msg = bufferedReader.lines().collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
    Log.d("Data", msg);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

[image]

**Can somebody please explain** -

- **Why is there a difference in the outputs as such?**
- **How can I get the entire output by running the command from application?**
- **What all requirements are there for the same?**

Comment: A related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43509440/running-ps-shell-command-on-android-programmatically

Answer (score 1):

adb shell is member of a lot of groups so it has a lot of privileges. It is not root, but it is as close as it gets. You can see the list of groups that the shell user is added by running `id` command from the terminal or check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16936187). On the other hand, your application runs in a sandbox and have very limited privileges. That's why you see a limited info when you run a command from the app code.

If you want to have unlimited access to the system from within your application, you need to request root access. You can do that by running the su command in a rooted phone:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
```

Comment: Hey @b4da thank you for the answer. Can you please clarify one more thing. There is a system service being developed which will be used to run the adb commands. Will the Runtime.getRuntime().exec("top -bn1") still require a rooted device and root access if it is being called from the system service to display the desired result as mentioned above?

Comment: @AbhiThakkar If you can add your service to system group (gid=1000) you can do pretty much anything you want.